# Toggle isn't changing back, and span ng-bind won't update to specified text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a log in page where when log in is clicked it changes to loggin in.... If the log in is incorrect, the log in button goes back to log in and the error message appears below. What is happening is that after log in is clicked, logging in.... stay even after the incorrect password is typed, and the error message does not update until after I focus the Email input. Thank you.
Html Log In File

```
<ion-view title="Login" id="page6">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form id="login-form4" class="list">
      <ion-list id="login-list2">
        <label class="item item-input" id="login-input10">
          <span class="input-label">Username/Email</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="UserInfo.email" placeholder="">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" id="login-input11">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="UserInfo.password" placeholder="">
        </label>
      </ion-list>
      <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
      <button id="login-button2" ng-click="login();login = !login" class="button button-positive  button-block">
      <span ng-show="login"> Log in</span>
      <span ng-hide="login">Logging in....</span>
      </button>
      <a ui-sref="signup" id="login-button3" class="button button-positive  button-block button-clear">Or create an account</a>
    </form>
    <span ng-bind="errorText"><font color="red"></font></span>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller File for login html

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'md5', 'Userid', '$state',// The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams,md5,Userid,$state) {

$scope.UserInfo = {};

$scope.login = true;

$scope.login =function(){







    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('URL');

    if ($scope.UserInfo.password == null){
        $scope.UserInfo.password = "fa";
    }
    console.log($scope.UserInfo.password);
    var query = client.getTable('USERID')
    .where({ Email: $scope.UserInfo.email, Password: md5.createHash($scope.UserInfo.password) })
    .read()
    .done(function(results) {


        if(results[0] == undefined)
        {
            console.log("undefined");
            $scope.errorText = "Error: Wrong Username Passowrd";
            $scope.login = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Userid.setJson(results[0].id);

            $state.go('tabsController.qRCode');
        }




    }, function(error) {
        console.log('an error occurred while checking login:');
        console.dir(error);
    });

$scope.UserInfo.password = "";


};



}])
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM will only update after a digest cycle is run. If you don't call it yourself, his only happens when an event is triggered such as clicking the email text box.

To run a digest cycle manually, call `$scope.$apply()` after you set `$scope.errorText`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: Yes that fixed the error message thank you, however the log in button is still stuck at "Logging in..."

Comment: If you want logging in.... to go away when the error message displays, you should use ng-show instead of ng-hide. The way you have it now, after the error message, $scope.login is set to false, so ng-hide=false, which means it doesn't hide, which means it DOES show. Also make sure to call $apply() after setting $scope.login to true